# Check for negative "unsign" interger does not work

Tags: anchor, solana-program, constraints

I have a function like this:

```
pub fn initialize_pool(ctx: Context<InitializePool>, rate: u64) -> Result<()> {
    require!(rate.gt(&0), SwapPoolError::SwapRateError);

    // {...more logic}

    Ok(())
}
```

I want to check if `rate` is equal or less than zero, throw an error here, however the function still passed with negative values (for example "new anchor.BN(-10)")

Besides above code I tried:

```
require!(rate > 0, SwapPoolError::SwapRateError);
```

and

```
if rate <= 0 
{
    return err!(SwapPoolError::SwapRateError);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rate` is defined as `u64`, an unsigned 64-bit integer, meaning that the 8 bytes that make up the number will always be interpreted as unsigned, greater than or equal to 0.

When you pass `-10`, that creates 8 bytes that are encoded as a signed integer. Your program doesn't know that, so it will interpret those 8 bytes as unsigned, and give an unexpected answer.

Here's some rust code that shows the issue:

```
fn main() {
    let i: i64 = -10;
    let u: u64 = i as u64;
    println!("{u}");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
18446744073709551606
```

which is the same as `u64::MAX - 9`. You can output what you're receiving in your program using the `msg!` macro.

Comment: I see, so what is the solution for this problem? Maybe change rate type to `i64` so it can check for negative numbers, but do we have more elegant solution?

Comment: The easiest solution is to just pass in a `u64` every time. If someone passes in an improper input, then that's a user error